# compose file seems to be unread

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created my own compose file and when I launch my services with `docker-compose up` it launch another services.

When I do `docker-compose run web` it doesn't recognized the service

Here is my compose file looks like :

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: my_image:tag
  data:
    image: my_image2:tag
```

Comment: are you in the correct directory ? Try to use the `-f` option to be sure that it uses the correct file

Comment: Are you in the folder where this docker compose file is? What is the name of the file?

Comment: Yes i'm in the correct directory, the compose file is docker-compose.yml. When i ran with elevated privileges (root) it works fine